# ONLY display certain rows from an inner joined table using a certain colum as a parameter from one of the inner joined tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables, one with various details such as

```
Username, email id, user code
```

and another table with columns which are:

```
UserCode, supervisor email id, active_flag
```

I required an output of a table which only displays the active users i.e. the users with `active_flag` (`Y` or `N`) column as 'Y'.

So as of now I have `Inner Joined` these two tables on `UserCode` as it exists in both and my table now looks like:

```
|Username| Email ID      | SuperVisor Email ID|
|Dan     | dan@gmail.com | ki.12@gmail.com    |
|John    | jon@gmail.com | ki.12@gmail.com    |
```

Is there a way that I can check from one of my tables the data from the column `ACTIVE_FLAG` and only display the active (`Y`) user details into this Inner Joined table?

I have searched on stack overflow but couldn't find a solution which I could use.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is as simple as adding a `WHERE active_flag = 'Y'` to the end of your query, after the `FROM .. join ..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly this should be what you're looking for

```
SELECT A.UserName, A.[Email ID], A.[Supervisor Email ID]
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.UserCode = B.UserCode
WHERE B.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help me with one more thing?
Now i wish to create a drop down in a grid view in asp .Net, Where i select the Username which i want. and the corresponding details appear. The help i need is once i select a name i don't want it to reappear in the drop down. Can i do that in my current Stored Procedure that i created? please help.

Comment: I would say you have to put in the logic that populates the dropdown ... select ... from yourtable where username not XXX where XXX is taken from the other controls